# How to use updated gps location data in main android activity?

Tags: android, gps, location

I have googled alot of questions and forums and could not find an answer so I hope this question does not repeat. If so, please direct me to the primary question.

Ok the thing is I do not know how to update gps location in android and then actually use this value in main activity. So I have a layout composed of two TextViews, one displaying longitude and another for displaying latitude. I have set one LocationManager, LocationListener (to update location) and then i call requestLocationUpdates() on my LocationManager as instructed in this tutorial http://www.firstdroid.com/2010/04/29/android-development-using-gps-to-get-current-location-2/

I use same onCreate and LocationListener methods as in tutorial above. As you can see onLocationChanged() makes a toast in this tutorial, but I would like to change text of my TextViews. Could you please show me how can I use values from getLongitude() (and similar methods) in my main activity.

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = “My current location is: “ +

“Latitud = “ + loc.getLatitude() +

“Longitud = “ + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your main activity, after `onCreate` and `setContentView` you need

```
EditText lat = new EditText findViewById(R.id.lat_view);
EditText lon = new EditText findViewById(R.id.lon_view);
```

(or whatever your lat & lon textviews are called in xml)

and then in your `onLocationChanged` add

```
lat.setText(loc.getLatitude);
lon.setText(loc.getLongitude);
```

you might need to make the `EditText`s static, im not in front of eclipse atm.

Answer (score 0):

from your main activity pass the textview in constructor of MyLocationListener(referring to tutorial you used).So basically you have to define a constructor in MyLocationListener

```
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
   Context context;
   TextView tv;      

   public MyLocationListener(Context context,TextView tv){
    this.context=context;
    this.tv=tv;
   }

  public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
      tv.setText("your text comes here");
  }      


}
```

and in main activity

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.yourTextViewId);
LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener(getApplicationContext(),tv);
```